How to get bot's conversation history with user in aiogram?
I'm making a telegram bot using the aiogram (v3.9.0) library for python (v3.11) and I need to access some previous messages in a conversation with a user. Please note that we are not talking about a group or channel, but about a private chat, where the user starts the bot with the /start command.
It so happened that I do not maintain a database of messages (I admit my mistake) and I do not have the ids of previous messages saved anywhere.
Is there a way to get the history of messages in a personal dialogue between a user and a bot, since it is stored on the server and is available to the user?
